# Tag issues (please add yours!)

Tags: discussion, tagging

One unique aspect of this site is/will be its tags—it already has more than some beta sites, and will end up (I suspect) having a simply huge number.

A site with a lot of tags is not a bad thing!

Tags that have been allowed to run wild, though, become nearly useless. The goal of this post is to be a place where the community can discuss various tag-related issues/options, and work together to keep its tags useful.

Questions? Concerns? Ideas? Suggestions? Add them here.

Comment: Make this a community wiki question?

Comment: Well, I only suggested this because this seems to be a question where there isn't any 'one right answer'.

Comment: I've noticed that new tag issues added to this question as answers are no longer getting much attention (or maybe I just added a few bad ones). Should we start making them one per question from now on like on other SE sites?

Comment: @Dori: Yes it seems the voters have been holding back too. I certainly don't expect you or the pro-tem's to rush through anything that nobody has voted on \-:

Answer (score 6):

I think we should really work on unique descriptions for our tags, especially for the geographic.
For example, [spain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) has this description:

> Travel relating to Spain

I think this is really bad to have such descriptions. Our user is not an idiot - he needs some additional info. Say, about sangria, Pyrenees, corrida and football, or something.

Comment: On the contrary I think the country tags would be too subjective if we tried to choose a few tidbits or highlights. Most people know where the country they are asking about is unless it's an exotic destination. Maybe listing bordering countries or agreements like EU or Shengen membership or something like democratic vs communist etc. But there's more that can go in a tag wiki than a tag excerpt too ...

Comment: @Dori: I took a shot at editing the Spain wiki if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: See point 2 of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ - your version looks quite close to breaking that... I've approved the edit though, so everyone can take a look at it and see what we all think!

Comment: Yes the tags page is an annoyance (but it's also good in other respects). I don't know why the excerpt editor has a much larger character limit than the tag page for on thing I consider this a bad design issue. But I've also filed a feature request for real-time preview of excerpts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95323/when-editing-tag-wiki-excerpts-show-a-live-preview-of-how-they-will-look-on-the-t

Comment: @hippietrail I wasn't commenting on the design, more on the rules it suggests on what you should and shouldn't put in tag pages. *2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized* - your expanded tag versions look to be running a risk of breaking that

Comment: @Gagravarr: Well for travel.SE the tag name already says it all in the case of names of countries so it doesn't really fit. We can either leave it blank, make it totally redundant, or not follow some of the advice on that blog post. What do you recommend instead?

Comment: We could have a boilerplate for all countries such as "Travel to, through, or from XXX" - but is that the best we could do for travel.SE? Maybe it is and we would have another boilerplate for cities and another for regions. But maybe it's not??

Comment: Personally I'd vote for something fairly short on the excerpt, maybe largely boiler plate, then a long one with other tag links (as you've done for Spain) on the main wiki, but I can't help feeling one of the other SE sites may have come up with a good model already!

Comment: People may wish to hold off on writing too many wiki excerpts until we've cleared this up - main wiki entries are being approved but excerpts are backed up in the mod queue, probably waiting for some clarity on what should be approved!

Comment: We could always move this one to its own issue. I don't think we can move the whole answer along with its comments though.

Answer (score 6):

Merge [castle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle) and [chateaux](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chateaux).

Yes I realize some people will view them as being different. But there are also plenty of people who will call a chateau a castle anyway and we've merged or suggested to merge other things which differ to greater degrees.

We could merge them under a tag such as [castles-and-chateaux](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castles-and-chateaux) but then what about palaces? Maybe [castles-etc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castles-etc) would be better and the tagwiki would explain what it covers and what it doesn't.

Comment: Every castle is a chateaux, but not every chateaux is a castle... so as chateaux is the more general word, it might be better taking that one? I definitely don't like "castles-etc"!

Comment: we have tag synonyms available so when you type one word, another word is used for the tag. Can we have a single word for large buildings that you visit for the building itself? chateau, castle, palace, even cathedral? or the gehry buildings? `architecture`? `buildings-to-visit`?

Comment: I guess "granularity" will come up here with tag merging more than on some other SE's. We can always adjust the granularity up or down as we evolve by merging or splitting tags as we find out just what our needs are.

Comment: I think [castles-and-palaces-and-chateaux] will be good :)

Comment: The [question about this on english.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47768/what-is-a-collective-term-for-castles-citadels-forts-palaces-etc) was a hit!

Answer (score 5):

I just made a new tag [sea-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-travel) as a cover tag for questions when travelling on water is important but the mode of travel is not. It would also work for travelling between Panama and Colombia for instance where there are no ferries or cruises.

Earlier I created [freighter-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freighter-travel) which is a specialist niche that mostly adventure travellers with plenty of money use.

We already had [ferry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ferry) and [cruise](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cruise) which are both pretty obvious and I don't think should be merged with any of the other seafaring tags. Cruises are very exotic in Australia compared to Europe and North America. They exist but I've never met anybody who's been on one.

So this tag issue is "don't merge any of these tags" but do feel free to discuss how they overlap etc.

Answer (score 4):

[image: checked off] 
Merge [sightseeing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sightseeing) and [must-see](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/must-see)?

The latter had been used only once until this morning when I added it to another question that used that wording since I knew the tag already existed.

I think "must see" while more specific is also more subjective so maybe those two qualities balance each other out.

In any case the latter is a subset of the former which is much more used.

Answer (score 3):

[image: checked off] 
There was a question with the tag [infant](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant) and we had another question asking about travelling with toddlers but with no specific tag.

Travel guides usually have a section titles along the lines of "travel with kids" so it is a typical topic.

I made a new tag [children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) which I added to both articles and removed the [infant](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant) tag.

My thinking was that we will have questions about children of various ages but still a relatively small number compares to other questions so in this case a broad tag covering children from infancy up to the age they can travel independently would be better than having multiple age-group kind of tags. More specific words like "toddler" or "infant" can go in the question title and body with the one broad tag.

Do others think I made the right call?

Comment: I also replaced the new tag [tag:family] with [tag:children] yesterday. This tag should also be merged. Perhaps [tag:family] might even be the better default tag for the synonym group?

Comment: This issue has been raised again [in a new question on separating some of these tags](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/248/tags-for-children-and-infant-baby), apparently unaware that it had already been discussed. Anyway I'm linking in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Should campervans and mobile homes / RV's be included in camping?

In Australia we don't really have the RV's of the extremely large size as in the US so we don't have dedicated RV parks as far as I know. In Canada and the US they do have them.

In Australia and Europe we have campervans and mobile homes which in my experience use the same campgrounds used for tents and caravans (called trailers in the US).

So I'm not sure whether to include RV's in [camping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping) but I would think not.

Then as to whether to include mobile homes and campervans is trickier because they have things more in common with camping, especially with caravans in some countries, but in north America it seems more natural to associate them with RV's.

So far I don't think we have any questions about RV's, mobile homes, or campervans so in the camping tag I've played it safe and only included tents and caravans /trailers.

Any ideas on what kind of grouping we should use or should we keep it this way until we get more questions?

Answer (score 3):

[image: checked off] 
Added [websites](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) synonym for [online-resources](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources).

https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/online-resources/synonyms

Answer (score 3):

[image: checked off] 
[israeli-citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israeli-citizen) should be plural, like the other country-citizens tags.

Comment: Yep I spotted that too.

Comment: Made this change.

Answer (score 2):

I was silly and created both the [resources](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and [reference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) tags in the last couple of hours or less. I know they are synonyms on at least one other SE I use so they were probably bound to come up sooner or later anyway.

Anyway I think they should be merged. I don't know if "reference" should be "references" since it works as both a countable and mass noun. I would assume the existing [internet-resources](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-resources) tag should also be moved in unless people feel a strong need to separate print and net resources for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[image: checked off] 
I added the [airport-security](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-security) tag to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/953/flight-mode-banned-on-ryanair-is-this-a-worldwide-phenomenon). Was I right or do we need [air-security](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-security)?

Comment: I think 'safety' is a better tag?

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee Damn it! I forgot about this one.

Comment: Actually there is a [tag:security] which we have decided not to merge with [tag:safety] so I'm going to check the question and probably retag. Since it's about whether the plane will crash and not about whether stuff will go missing from your luggage then "safety" is definitely the right tag for this question and "security" of any form is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[image: checked off] 
[automobiles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automobiles) should be a synonym of [cars](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) (which would need to be created).

"Automobile" is only used in USA as far as I know and is quite a quirky sounding word. "Car" on the other hand is used in all English speaking countries as far as I know, including the US.

Answer (score 2):

[image: checked off] 
Should [attractions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attractions) be merged into [sightseeing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sightseeing)? I'm in two minds but one thing to think about is that [must-see](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/must-see) has already been made a synonym of [sightseeing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sightseeing) but that phrase applies equally well to [attractions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attractions).

Answer (score 2):

### Culture

Is [culture](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) a useful tag? I see it, at best, as not adding any value, and at worst, a problematic tag that will not have a satisfactory definition. There are huge academic debates about what the proper definition of "culture" is, and it's also just so broad a term that I don't think it's really helpful to include.

I bring up this issue because I was going to start going through and proposing tag wiki excerpts for some of the blank tags, and as I started to write out a description for [culture](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) I realized that I don't think it's a necessary tag.

The current questions for that tag benefit much more from their other tags than the culture one. My tag wiki excerpt started off with "The customs, behavior, language, attitudes, art and social institutions of a group" - but we already have [local-customs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-customs) [language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) as well as tags for specific cultures like [aboriginal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aboriginal) [maori](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maori) etc.

It seems to me that most questions that have been asked and possibly will be asked are covered by other tags, especially [local-customs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-customs) [language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and [food-and-drink](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-and-drink).

Does anyone else have thoughts on removing this tag?

Comment: I think it's closest to [tag:local-custums], so close it could be a synonyms. In fact maybe "culture" is even better since we only use the two-word "local-customs" to differentiate it from the place where you declare things you're importing at borders and airports. I do think it's useful but I don't think both are useful.

Answer (score 2):

Could someone make [brasil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brasil) a synonym of [brazil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazil)?

This is as obvious as it gets, but because I don't have any rep in the Brazil tag, personally I cannot even *vote* for the synonym to be created.

(On a site like ours, the Stack Exchange tag synonym system is far from optimal. It would be helpful if e.g. [trusted users](https://travel.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) could do more, even just something like voting for *any* tag synonym.)

---

Also, on meta, could someone finally make `tags` and `tagging` synonyms? (Yes, this issue is as minor and as meta as it gets...)

Comment: Agree, the synonym system is really annoying. Can't propose this synonym too.

Answer (score 1):

### High speed rail

Right now, the only rail transport related tag is 'high speed rail'? Should it a new tag, say, 'rail travel' (like the existing 'air travel' tag) be created instead, and 'high speed rail' and 'train' be made synonyms of this?

Comment: We have [tag:train] and [tag:high-speed-rail]. Travel on high speed trains is in some way more like a plane that travels on rails, and so there are quite a few things that are specific to them.

Answer (score 1):

[image: checked off] 
Shouldn't [money](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) be the "lead tag" rather than [currency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency)? They are currently merged with the latter as the "lead tag" and "money" as a synonym.

But at least to my "currency" pretty much means the actual cash money of a particular country and many of the questions so tagged are talking much more generally including credit cards, debit cards, ATMs, etc. I think [money](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) is the more general term which would better suit such general types of questions.

Comment: Looks like they have been swapped; `money` is the main tag now. Delete this post maybe?

Answer (score 1):

### No questions tagged with this tag as of August 2017

[fukushima](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fukushima) should refer either to the prefecture or the capital (or just be a disambiguation page), and should not refer to the nuclear incident.

It's easier to add disambiguation to a nuclear incident than to a state/prefecture (though sometimes it can't be helped, such as Georgia).

Also, merely referring to an incident by its location can stigmatize a place. I understand that it's convenient in everyday conversation, but it shouldn't be used everywhere.

Comment: For me Fukushima refers to both the prefecture and its capital which has the same name. There's no need to have both separeate. Maybe one day there will be. Also there are other places with the same name but so far no questions about them. I agree with you about the incident though.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally created milesmore. This badge should be deleted or at least renamed to miles-and-more and then a synonym should related to loyality-programs.

Comment: We now have [tag:miles-and-more], but what were you proposing with regards to [tag:loyalty-programs]?

Answer (score 0):

On meta, [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) seem similar. Can someone include in the tag wiki how to distinguish them?

Likewise, what's the difference between [extreme-tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-tourism) and [adventure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure)?

Comment: Extreme tourism is about risk. Adventure is about being epic. Bungie jumping is an extreme sport. Hitchhiking across Russia from Finland to Japan would be an adventure. I've been trying to think of wording for these tags for ages but being a perfectionist I always come up short. The best way to get a feel for the difference is to look at the types of questions tagged each way. Of course some things are both extreme and adventures. Also some questions may have the wrong tag and some may be hard to tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some questions tagged with [islam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam) which are about discrimination against Muslims, which don't require any knowledge about the religion Islam itself. I think they should not be tagged with "islam", because it isn't really about Islam, and instead should only be tagged with [discrimination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrimination).

Examples:

- [Does the UK visa system discriminate against Muslims?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61153/does-the-uk-visa-system-discriminate-against-muslims)
- [What are the consequences of Trump's election for Muslims visiting the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82213/what-are-the-consequences-of-trumps-election-for-muslims-visiting-the-us)
- [Is it dangerous to travel in Russia, as a dark-skinned Muslim?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87753/is-it-dangerous-to-travel-in-russia-as-a-dark-skinned-muslim)
- [Visiting Russia as an Arab. Am I going to be hassled?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60866/visiting-russia-as-an-arab-am-i-going-to-be-hassled) (question is about someone of Arab appearance, but the previous question was closed as a duplicate of this one. Doesn't have "islam" or "discrimination")
- [Do people in Georgia (the country) have any dislike of Muslims?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/do-people-in-georgia-the-country-have-any-dislike-of-muslims)

Upvote or retag if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

Should things suspected of being a scam by the OP, but turn out not to be, be tagged [scam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scam)? Example question, currently not tagged: [International driver's licence (IDD): is this site reliable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/international-drivers-licence-idd-is-this-site-reliable)

Answer (score -1):

A tag for each contry is a must. We cannot do anything about them, but I think istead of having too many tags, we should have tag combinations.

We have (india), (indian-citizens) similarly we have (italy)(italian-citizens), similarlly for all countries, instead of all the (*****-citizens) tags, we can have a single (-citizens) tag.
And all the users will be required to tag their questions with both (india) and (-citizens) (lets say).

Comment: Can you elaborate your proposal a little bit more? I don't understand it completely. At the moment we have a tag for each country (if there are any questions about that country), but what do you mean by tag combinations?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I have edited my answer.

Comment: We distinguish between the country India and the Indian-citizens tag mainly because of visa questions. If you're asking a question about a visa (to get into another country, not necessarily India) it is very important to know you're citizenship. Therefore you should then use the tag indian-citizens. But if you ask a question about India, the country, you used use India.

Comment: combining tages by using [us] and [-citizens] is not how tags should work.