# Do we need to define tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

There's been a bunch of really well meaning people defining tag wikis for all kinds of things that [we don't really need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts/96486#96486).

- please don't copy information from wikipedia to a tag wiki
- please don't define very simple terms (i.e. if the tag is London, you don't need to write that London is a city in the UK)

There's more info on [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts/96486#96486), but since I saw a lot of people doing this, I wanted to post a note here. I didn't want people to waste their time (even though the help was very appreciated).

Comment: Is it really considered OK to have totally blank tag wikis? Admittedly everybody should know where London is but not everybody will know where Tbilisi is and it seems sensible to take the same approach for all cities. I thought putting what state/province/area of which country and whether it was the capital or biggest city would be a good minimal format.

Comment: @hippietrail yes it is perfectly fine for them to be blank.

Comment: There's nothing in the link you provided about blank tags. If by "don't define" you do not mean blank then what do you mean?

Comment: Are there some precedents for blank tag wikis? All the obvious ones I know on my other SE's are not blank. Do you propose leaving every city tag blank or do you propose where to draw the line between "very simple terms" and "not so simple terms" when it comes to cities?

Comment: @Matthew please read the answer linked to by Jeff which explains why defining simple terms is not what the tag wiki is for : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/can-we-please-have-better-tag-wikis-and-excerpts/96486#96486

Comment: Ah, apologies, I was working with a much more loose definition of "define".  Defining may be bad for simple terms, yes.  "Filling out the tag wiki appropriately can be useful even for simple tags" is the idea I intended to convey.  My bad.

Answer (score 4):

There's been some discussions on [Tag issues (please add yours!)](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/tag-issues-please-add-yours/71#71) for this already

The conclusion seemed to be that the excerpts should be short, and the wiki itself should have some more detail along with links to related tags

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it would harm if the excerpt for the [london](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london) tag said

> Capital of Great Britain.

After all, [London might not be as unique as you think...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_%28disambiguation%29)

Comment: Indeed, the London that often pops to mind for me is London, Ontario, Canada.