# Tags for children and infant/baby

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

It looks like someone combined the infant tag with children. I realise that we probably don't want tags for every age of child, but I'd think that the challenges for travelling with a baby are different from children that are able to walk and talk that it would be worth differentiating. Then again, I don't have the experience yet to know -- maybe the challenges are similar?

Comment: Let's wait for the mod who made the merge to weigh in. Personally, I agree with Mark and g that the two tags can be separate.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for separation, given diaper/feeding/nursing issues of babies on trains/planes vs travel with kids - definitely different issues.  Prices also differ - infants are often free.  Understand where you're coming from.  Others may disagree though?

Answer (score 3):

The tags and whether to keep separate or merge [was discussed in the general tag issues thread](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/tag-issues-please-add-yours/202#202) but not many people bothered to comment on it at the time.

I was just "being bold" since the few votes seemed to think it was a good idea to lump them together but certainly feel free to discuss and change them. I think [Dori](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74/dori) did the original merging and then I added more to my answer later.

One problem might be where the [family](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family) fits in if putting children of different ages in different tags?

Comment: Valid arguments from both sides! Argh! The horror!

Comment: Wouldn't `family` be a generic tag with specific tags for the various different groups within that - elderly, pregnant, teenage, baby, etc - each having specific travel needs.

Comment: @Remou: That would be one way to do it. At the time I proposed merging them all it seemed we were doing a lot more "lumping" of tags than "splitting". I think it boils down to having tags for topics once the topic has a cluster of questions, not splitting a tag for just one question or possible future questions. And of course keeping in mind that we can always split or merge tags in the future as we see how the site develops.