# Meta tags - time to eradicate?

Tags: discussion, tagging

As Laura pointed out in [Should we remove the "culture" tag?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/should-we-remove-the-culture-tag), some tags are bordering on being solely subjective.

As per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ the intent on SE sites is to slay the evil meta or subjective tag.

So I propose - if you have a meta tag you'd like culled, add it as an answer below.

If you see an answer you also want killed, vote for it. If not, vote it down.

So:

- +1 = kill it
- -1 = keep it

and we'll see how that looks, and then review.

Comment: err, to whoever is voting the question down, no, bad, you're meant to be voting answers up or down in this example ;) Unless you really just want every single tag to exist.

Comment: The stuff I'm seeing here looks like they're not good tags, but they aren't necessarily *meta* tags. They're just plain too broad or ambiguous for most scenarios (and thus equally deserving of eradication should the case come to it)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's much use for [countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries). I think I've even tried to nurture it after somebody invented it by putting it on questions talking about more than one country, or asking how to choose between some. But I don't think that's enough.

If you think ***countries*** is a bad meta tag, Vote up.

If you think ***countries*** can hold its own as a real tag, Vote down.

Comment: Well we never got rid of this one either. It's most used with questions comparing countries I believe. Much like [tag:destinations] but both more and less specific.

Answer (score 6):

[destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations).  To me, every travel question is almost certainly going to have a destination (Aside from "currency" related, or mile-high club ones).

If you think [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations) is a bad meta tag, vote up.

If you think [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations) is a real and valid tag, vote down.

Comment: I think it's a bad tag. I don't think it's a meta tag. But we never got rid of it, which I took to be a mandate that it ought to be used, so I've used it a few times a year.

Comment: @pnuts well the 6 upvotes seemed to think it's bad, I'll give you that, but this was 4 years ago. I think we did actually clear it out at the time :/