# Are meta tags OK now, or do we just not know what meta tags are, or have we decided to ignore Stack Exchange policies?

Tags: discussion, tagging, policy, stackexchange

Six years ago, our venerable overlords at Stack Exchange had a hissy fit about what it calls "meta tags":

> **[The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)**

We have also discussed them at least once, four and a half years back:

> **[Meta tags - time to eradicate?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/meta-tags-time-to-eradicate)** (Though the tags we actually discuss are bad for other reasons and are not meta tags as Stack Exchange defines them.)

Anyway, I've just noticed we have a meta tag [rationale](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rationale) with in the vicinity of 100 questions.

What shall we do with it?

What shall we do in regard to the Stack Exchange policy against meta tags?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of "rationale" questions in general, but there was some earlier discussion in *[The tag 'rationale' has no rationale](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3633)*

Comment: What is meta about this tag?

Comment: This question is a dupe but there is no resolution on the other one. Let's actually do something about it.

Comment: @hippietrail, I'm in, why not proceed from here with your proposal?

Comment: Picking up the discussion on the other question